# “How to fix ‘format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)’ error in C”

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing the cs50,get a question about the function,I can't understant the differance between this two codes.why the first got an error?
[image]

just on the cs50 sandbox

My code(got an error)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
    int num = get_positive_int("Height:");
}

int get_positive_int(string prompt)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        num=get_int(prompt);
    }
    while(num<1);
    return num;
}
```

Right code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int get_positive_int(void);
int main(void)
{
    int i = get_positive_int();
}
// Prompt user for positive integer
int get_positive_int(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: That's why it isn't a default warning.  It isn't always helpful.  There are definitely circumstances where it identifies real problems, especially if the user of the program (rather than the programmer) can control the format string.  In this context, it isn't a significant problem (I'd argue it isn't a problem at all).

Comment: As to how to fix it — you have to replace the variable with a constant string, which is a pain for I18N/L10N (essentially impossible), and a nuisance for utility functions like these.

Comment: You might try `get_int("%s", prompt)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first code sample compiler complains "not a string literal" for the first argument passed to get_int() function call at line #15. The reason is the definition of get_int() in [cs50.h with a special attribute](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/ee9052d/src/cs50.h#L87):

```
int get_int(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
```

The "format" [attribute is a GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to the C/C++ standard by which we can ask compiler to enforce more checks against our source code. In your example, we want compiler to run type-check against the first argument of get_int(). In order to run the type check, compiler is expecting a literal value instead of a variable as the first argument of get_int().

The right code sample contains string literal where expected, so allows compiler to run type check and compiles without issue:

```
n = get_int("Height: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

a string literal in C : "this is a string literal" is of the type (const char*)

but since you passed it as an argument to a function that take a (string) variable, your variable got implicitly casted into a string which appears not to be a valid argument for the get_int() function

try this code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(const char* prompt);

int main(void)
{
    int num = get_positive_int("Height:");
}

int get_positive_int(const char* prompt)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        num=get_int(prompt);
    }
    while(num<1);
    return num;
}
```